# what does bold edges mean?

Tags: edges

I'm learning how to use blender and sometimes I use wrong tools accidentally. I just realize that one of my wall has bold edges as you can see below. I don't know how I did that. What does that mean and how can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: @zeffii there is only import-export and render addons enabled

Comment: It would be interesting to take a look at your file, which you can upload to [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). The problem could be in edited user preferences thus resulting in changed effect for something usual. As of your answer I can add that double vertices won't be marked like that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have accidentally apply either of these to the edges

1. Edge Creasing
2. Mark Sharp

You can try these steps

1. Go into Edit Mode.
2. Select **Edge Selection mode**
3. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all edges.
4. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>,and set **Edge Crease** to Zero value.
5. Hit <kbd>Cltr</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, look for "**Clear Sharp**"

Hope that helps.